# UIImage doesn't copy into Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to view an image previously selected in ImagePickerView... 
This is my code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    coffeeObj.coffeeImage=[image copy];

//    imagePreview.image=    coffeeObj.coffeeImage;

    [imagePreview setImage:coffeeObj.coffeeImage];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Obviously coffeeObj.coffeeImage is a UIImage variable but it doesn't work at all...
But if I create a new UIImage variable in this function, works perfectly.
I can write in the coffeObj because if I do:

```
coffeeObj.name=@"Ciao";
```

I view the variable name changed.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Use [image copy]; instead of image when assign to your variable.

Comment: `coffeeObj.coffeeImage=[image copy];` Right?

Comment: Yes, this must work.

Comment: No, I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: What is reference type of coffeeImage? Weak or strong?

Comment: Why do you use deprecated method? Use 
`-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` instead and get your `UIImage` with `info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]`

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) Coffee *coffeeObj;

Comment: I will edit my post with updated and not deprecated method

Comment: Have you checked that the image comes from the method is not nil?

Comment: Yes, if I do `[imagePreview setImage: image];` works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    coffeeObj.coffeeImage=image;

    imagePreview.image=    coffeeObj.coffeeImage;

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The other method is deprecated.

Comment: IDE doesn't tell that the method is deprecated... Anyway i tried your method but it doesn't work

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: Maybe a bug, but check how you init the imagePreview and coffeeObj.

Comment: coffeObj is passed from another class and is != null and contains all information I need to know

Comment: coffeImage declaration?

Comment: `@interface Coffee : NSObject {

 NSInteger coffeeID;
 NSString *nome;
 NSString * Description;
 UIImage *coffeeImage; 
    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger coffeeID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nome;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Description;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double Latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double Longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *coffeeImage;
`

Comment: if you don't synthesize coffeImage i don't know what is happening xD

Answer (score 0):

Check the interface declaration of `Coffee` class and make sure that `coffeeImage` is stored as a strong reference

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *coffeeImage;
```

Comment: Ok now I changed to `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *coffeeImage;` but nothing